# How do I get my Qt console app to communicate with another Qt gui app?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

My project needs to have two parts to it. The first part where input is taken from a Qt console window. The input is processed and a signal is sent to the Qt gui app (the second part) which accordingly updates the UI. How Do I implement this? Can these be a part of the same app, or do I need to keep the two separate and communicate between the two?

Please direct me to the specific classes and functions I would have to use.

I've had a look at QProcess but wasn't sure whether that would serve the purpose.

Comment: The term for two processes communicating is "Inter-Process Communication" or IPC. There's a page laying out the various methods of IPC supported directly by Qt here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ipc.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is not possible to run both console and GUI application in Qt. You can try create .exe file which will be your console and another .exe which will be the GUI application.

To run console from GUI application you should use `QProcess` where you have to specify the absolute path to your console executable.

More information about `QProcess` you can found [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on UNIX or GNU/Linux systems, you can use [QtDBus](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtdbus-module.html#qtdbus) module.
You can write 2 softwares, one using a console, the other using GUI and make them communicating through D-Bus. You can find some examples [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-dbus.html).

> The QtDBus module is a Unix-only library you can use to implement IPC using the D-Bus protocol. It extends Qt's Signals and Slots mechanism to the IPC level, allowing a signal emitted by one process to be connected to a slot in another process. This D-Bus page has detailed information on how to use the QtDBus module.

Also, you can use TCP/IP sockets wrapped by Qt to communicate. This is a portable solution.
[Qt Fortune Server](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneserver-example.html) and [Qt Fortune Client](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneclient-example.html) are examples well written and explained step by step.

Every solutions for Inter Process Communication (IPC) proposed by Qt is proposed on this [page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/ipc.html).

Answer (score 0):

As Qt 5.9, there is module which is currently under technology preview name [QtRemoteObjects](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtremoteobjects-index.html) which provides Qt native IPC for QObjects, its easy to use and could be used to share signal/slots and also models between two processes